# Reset Setting Android Studio 4.1.2

Tags: android-studio

How to reset all setting in android studio 4.1.2 , please help me to fix this problem.
I have work right now and my Android studio have been error.

Answer (score 5):

In your Android Studio go to File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings.